# Redirect when click on "response" in comment section

Tags: comments, redirect

I use a custom template for some of my categories. These categories offer a comment section in which a user can reply to an comment.

The problem is, that the use (after clicking on the reply link) is redirected to the default singele-view template. Can I change the redirect target to my custom post page? Is there any hook or filter?

I had the same problem after submitting the comment, but this could be solved by adding a filter/action 'comment_post_redirect'.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So you'd like to be able to reply inline? Is this template a custom page template, or is it a category archive template? Or is it a category specific category archive template? Where can we find your code?

Comment: It's a custom template. For these categoriesI don't want to use the default single.php. So I created a template file which gets the current post over $_GET parameters (e.g. http://website.de/forum/?post=123). Unfortunatelly since I updated to the newest WP-version, the reply function in the comments section redirects to the default single.php (which has no comment-section) instead of redirecting to my custom template/URL. All I need, is to change the redirect path. But I don't know how^^

Comment: So you're unaware of `category.php` or it's siblings, or the taxonomy system? This could be implemented using rewrite rule endpoints to load a different template, or custom post types

Comment: @Brotzka are you still having an issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an alternative comments template that is based off of the regular Wordpress template, and create a link in place of the "respond" button that links to your custom post.

Instead of calling

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Just call

```
<?php comments_template('/custom-comments.php'); ?>
```

Here's the Wordpress article for reference - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template

Comment: I use a custom comment section (see http://pastebin.com/1uyZb5Gi for a detailed view). Like I said in the comment above, the problem occures since I updated to the newest version of WP (4.4). Before that update, everything worked fine.